# how to put routing and pages together

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, view, laravel-blade

I am pretty new to Laravel, I am so confused on how to start this. but basically I have a switch statement with different display mode cases and what I am trying to do is to connect routing with blade. How do I display $mycontent in blade based on cases like these ? Thanks

```
switch(MyPage::$some_display_mode) {

case 'normal':
 $mycontent //this is what I want to display in blade

case 'ajax':


case 'other'
}
```

I want to connect these cases normal,ajax ,other etc with with different MyPages that I have so that I can display my blade files something like this

```
<html>
@yield('content)
</html>


@section('content')
whatever comes from the pages
@endsection
```

Comment: where are you doing the switch?

Comment: it's just my starting point , so right now it is in the view, i'd like to connect my route to the view and later separate it into Controller

Answer (score 1):

You can use route groups and do something similar to this:

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'AJAX', 'namespace' => 'AJAX' ], function()   {

   Route::get( '/something', 'ajaxController@doSomething' );

});
```

There is multiple ways to group routes shown here:

[laravel grouped routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups)

Then handle returning the view in the controller and the use template-inheritance as explaned here:

[laravel template-inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#template-inheritance)

This way will allow you to group and keep your routes organized